# $scope value is not showing in other controller, And how can I set marker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have 2 controllers,

**In the first controller I have assign latitude, longitude values**

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) 
{
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
    {
        $scope.PostJobData.latitude=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        $scope.PostJobData.longitude=results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    }
});
```

**My view page from this I have called another controller**

```
<div ng-controller="getmap">
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" events="map.events">
    <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="m in map.markers" coords="m.coords" icon="m.icon" idkey="m.id"></ui-gmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

**2nd controller from this I am trying to access latitude, longitude values but it showing undefined**

```
.controller('getmap', function ($scope) {
    alert($scope.PostJobData.latitude);
    alert($scope.PostJobData.longitude);

   angular.extend($scope, {
        map: {
            center: {
                latitude: $scope.PostJobData.latitude,
                longitude: $scope.PostJobData.longitude
            },
            zoom: 11,
            markers: [],
            events: {
            click: function (map, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
                var e = originalEventArgs[0];
                var lat = e.latLng.lat(),lon = e.latLng.lng();
                var marker = {
                    id: Date.now(),
                    coords: {
                        latitude: lat,
                        longitude: lon
                    }
                };
                $scope.map.markers.push(marker);
                console.log($scope.map.markers);
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        }
        }
    });
})
```

**Error**

> Error - angular-google-maps: could not find a valid center property

**question**

> 1- How can I get latitude, longitude values on another controller
>
> 2-how can I able to create maker with a different icon ?

**--------------- New Updat what I hv done by below answer  -----------------**

```
.controller('PostJob',['$scope', '$rootScope','$http','$state','commonService','FileUploader', function($scope, $rootScope, $http,$state,commonService,FileUploader,createMap)
```

Injected createMap

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
            {
                $scope.PostJobData.latitude=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                $scope.PostJobData.longitude=results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                createMap.setlatValue(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                createMap.setlogValue(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            }
        });
```

Service -

```
app.service('createMap', function () {
     var latValue = [];
     var logValue= [];

    this.getlatValue = function () {
       return latValue; 
    }

    this.setlatValue = function (latitude) {
       console.log(latitude);
       latValue = latitude;
    }

    this.getlogValue = function () {
     return logValue;
    }

    this.setlogValue = function (longitude) {
     console.log(longitude);
      logValue = longitude;
    }
});
```

Another Controller -

```
.controller('getmap', function ($scope,createMap) {
    alert($scope.PostJobData.latitude);
    alert($scope.PostJobData.longitude);

   angular.extend($scope, {
        map: {
            center: {
                latitude: createMap.getlatValue(),
                longitude: createMap.getlogValue()
            },
            zoom: 11,
            markers: [],
            events: {
            click: function (map, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
                var e = originalEventArgs[0];
                var lat = e.latLng.lat(),lon = e.latLng.lng();
                var marker = {
                    id: Date.now(),
                    coords: {
                        latitude: lat,
                        longitude: lon
                    }
                };
                $scope.map.markers.push(marker);
                console.log($scope.map.markers);
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        }
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: you should use services in order to comunicate between controllers

Comment: Means, we are able to use $scope variables on another controller ?

Comment: $scope variable is act like glue between the controller and template it is not used to share the data to one ctrl to another inorder to communicate you have to use `services` or `$rootscope`

Comment: `.controller('PostJob',['$scope', '$rootScope','$http','$state','commonService','FileUploader', function($scope, $rootScope, $http,$state,commonService,FileUploader,createMap)`  you have forgot to anitate it shoul be like this  `.controller('PostJob',['$scope', '$rootScope','$http','$state','commonService','FileUploader', createMap,function($scope, $rootScope, $http,$state,commonService,FileUploader,createMap)`

Comment: createMap.getlatValue() && createMap.getlogValue() responce is null

Comment: `$scope.PostJobData.latitude=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                $scope.PostJobData.longitude=results[0].geometry.location.lng();`  check this line what are you getting in this it looks like there is no value in this variable but the way i do is correct you should send the data with the value in side the createMap.setlatValue("your data with latitude") then you can see in console the value

Comment: createMap.setlatValue(results[0].geometry.location.lat());           createMap.setlogValue(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
console.log('1--'+$scope.PostJobData.latitude);
console.log('2--'+createMap.getlatValue());

Comment: Value is getting on both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115938/discussion-between-anand-jain-and-mohan-gopi).

Answer (score 1):

Create a services

```
.service('mydata', function () {
     var latValue = [];
     var logValue= [];

    this.getlatValue = function () {
       return latValue; 
    }

    this.setlatValue = function (latitude) {
       console.log(latitude);
       latValue = latitude;
    }

    this.getlogValue = function () {
     return logValue;
    }

    this.setlogValue = function (longitude) {
     console.log(longitude);
      logValue = longitude;
    }
})
```

inside your fist controller this

```
.controller('myCtrl', functio($scope,mydata){ //you can see i have injucted mydata service to the controller 

     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) 
{
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
    {
        $scope.PostJobData.latitude=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        $scope.PostJobData.longitude=results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        mydata.setlatValue(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
        mydata.setlogValue(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
    }
});

});
```

and your second controller should be like this

```
.controller('getmap', function ($scope , mydata) { //you can see i have injucted mydata service to the controller
    alert($scope.PostJobData.latitude);
    alert($scope.PostJobData.longitude);

   angular.extend($scope, {
        map: {
            center: {
                latitude: mydata.getlatValue();
                longitude: mydata.getlogValue();
            },
            zoom: 11,
            markers: [],
            events: {
            click: function (map, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
                var e = originalEventArgs[0];
                var lat = e.latLng.lat(),lon = e.latLng.lng();
                var marker = {
                    id: Date.now(),
                    coords: {
                        latitude: lat,
                        longitude: lon
                    }
                };
                $scope.map.markers.push(marker);
                console.log($scope.map.markers);
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        }
        }
    });
})
```

and i dont have any idea about your second question

Comment: Getting Error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setlatValue' of undefined

Comment: Update your question up to what you have done let me see

Comment: Thanks for help @mohan Gopi